# Haskell higher order function to calculate length

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I can't understand what's happening here? Can anybody please explain this code? 
How does this function calculate the length?

```
callength = foldr (\_ n -> 1 + n) 0
```

Why does it use lambda, underscore, space between underscore and n and zero on the right hand side?

Comment: I think you will find the answer to that question in like a third chapter of any book about Haskell. This is a very basic stuff.

Comment: If you don't like the lambda, you can use `foldr (((+1).).(flip const)) 0` instead...

Comment: Do you know what `foldr` is and how it works? Well, ehird gave a pretty thorough explanation of it anyhow. [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) comes highly recommended as a "getting started with Haskell" book, explaining lambdas, underscores, folds, functions, etc.

Answer (score 19):

`(\_ n -> 1 + n)`  simply means a function that takes two arguments, and returns one more than its second argument. The underscore simply means that a parameter is ignored. For comparison, as a top-level declaration without using a wildcard pattern (the underscore), this function would look like:

```
foo x n = 1 + n
```

Now, here's an example list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is actually just syntactic sugar for:

```
1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : []
```

What `foldr` does is recursively replace each `(:)` with the function it's given, and the `[]` with the argument after the function (the *zero*). So, `foldr f z [1, 2, 3, 4]` for any `f` and `z` looks like this:

```
f 1 (f 2 (f 3 (f 4 z)))
```

(This is why `foldr (:) []` just returns back the same list you give it — it ends up reconstructing the original list structure.)

In this case, using the function `foo` and the zero 0, it looks like:

```
foo 1 (foo 2 (foo 3 (foo 4 0)))
```

We know that `foo` ignores its first argument, and returns one more than its second argument. So this is the same as:

```
1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + 0)))
```

which is 4, the length of the list. Basically, the fold ignores every element of the list, and just adds one to an accumulator for every element, giving the length. The 0 is used to end the whole process, and because the length of the empty list is 0.

To see this in more detail, we can expand each call step-by-step:

```
foldr foo 0 (1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : [])
foo 1 (foldr foo 0 (2 : 3 : 4 : []))
1 + foldr foo 0 (2 : 3 : 4 : [])
1 + foo 2 (foldr foo 0 (3 : 4 : []))
1 + 1 + foldr foo 0 (3 : 4 : [])
1 + 1 + foo 3 (foldr foo 0 (4 : []))
1 + 1 + 1 + foldr foo 0 (4 : [])
1 + 1 + 1 + foo 4 (foldr foo 0 [])
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + foldr foo 0 []
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0
1 + 1 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 2
1 + 3
4
```

Comment: Wow.  That was a very patient explanation of key Haskell basics.  +1.