# Haskell function for list length

Tags: haskell, fold

To calculate length of a list, using a foldr, one would do something like:

```
foldr (\_ acc -> acc + 1) 0
```

Expanding further on the idea that the folding function needs to increment the second argument, i came up with this (and it's wrong):

```
foldr ((+1) . (flip const)) 0`
```

Further inspection of the type reveals this:

```
(+1) . (flip const) :: Num (c -> c) => a -> c -> c
```

[Haskell higher order function to calculate length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297320/haskell-higher-order-function-to-calculate-length)
There's an interesting comment on that page, which i can't understand really

```
foldr (((+1).).(flip const)) 0
```

Can someone explain how does that composition actually work ?

Comment: This looks like it was generated with some tool, like [pointfree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree)....

`(+1) . (flip const)` basically means add one for every application of this function, regardless of the first parameter (that's what the flip const is there for). It's like `(\a b -> (b+1))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, let's focus why `foldr ((+1) . (flip const)) 0` is wrong. You want to increment the second argument only and forget the first one. Semantically, that's

```
\_ a -> a + 1
```

However, you wrote the following:

```
(+1) . flip const
= (+1) . (\_ a -> a)
= \x -> (+1) . (\_ a -> a) $ x
= \x -> (+1) $ (\_ a -> a) $ x
= \x -> (+1) $ \a -> a
= \_ -> (+1) (\a -> a)
= const ( (+1) (\a -> a))
```

Which is why you suddenly need `Num (c -> c)`, since you're trying to apply `(+1)` on `id`.

But you actually meant:

```
\_ a -> a + 1
= \_ a -> (+1) a
= \_   -> (+1)
= const (+1)
```

After all, you want to forget the first argument and use a function `f` on the second. All you have to to is to use `const f`.

The composition `((+1).).(flip const)` is overly verbose and probably generated by [pointfree](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree#Tool_support):

```
((+1).).(flip const)
= ((\x -> x + 1).) . (\a _ -> a)
= \c -> ((\x -> x + 1).) . (\a _ -> a) $ c
= \c -> ((\x -> x + 1).) $ \_ -> c
= \c -> \f -> (\x -> x + 1) . f $ \_ -> c
= \c ->   (\x -> x + 1) . \_ -> c
= \_ c -> (\x -> x + 1) $ c
= \_ c -> c + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is really a comment, but much too long for one.

Unless you're dealing with weird numbers like lazy `Nat`s, you really want

```
length xs = foldl' (\acc _ -> 1 + acc) 0 xs
```

Making this pointless,

```
length = foldl' (\acc -> const ((1+) acc)) 0
length = foldl' (const . (1+)) 0
```

If you like, you can transform the original `foldl'` expression into a `foldr` form like so:

```
length xs = foldr go id xs 0 where
  go _ r acc = r $! 1 + acc
```

Chewing on `go`,

```
go _ r acc = ($!) r $ (+) 1 acc
go _ r = ($!) r . (+1)
go _ r = (. (+1)) (($!) r)
go _ = (. (+1)) . ($!)
go = const ((. (+1)) . ($!))
```

Chewing on `length`,

```
length = flip (foldr go id) 0
```

Putting it all together,

```
length = flip (foldr (const ((. (+1)) . ($!))) id) 0
```

I, for one, find this point-free form utterly opaque.

Comment: `foldl' (flip ((+).const 1)) 0` works, too. `flip` goes to `foldl'`s reversed order of arguments to the combining function, and `((+).f)` is fold+map fusion; so it is semi-readable. --- another one is  `foldl' ((. const 1).(+)) 0`. :)

Comment: I really like you answer!
`foldl' (const . (1+)) 0` is definitely the best.
Here is another version which increments the argument inside const: `foldl (on const (+1)) 0`